# inspect Flash XMLSocket traffic

Tags: flash, inspect, xmlsocket

### first of all, I know that Flash reached its End Of Life. but I can't convert the SWF file into HTML5 as I am not the developer of it, I am just a user.

there is an SWF file running on a web page.
this SWF sends and receives data using a Flash XMLSocket.
I wanna inspect that traffic.
I tried Firefox Firebug, Chrome developer tools, Fiddler everywhere & Charles proxy debugger.
I can't catch the traffic, I am sure there is a traffic but I can't catch it.
The SWF is made with ActionScript 2.0
my OS is Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.
it is better if there is a solution to inspect that traffic using Python 3 PyQt5 QtWebEngine. 
EDIT: Charles Proxy can catch the HTTPS traffic,but not XMLSocket traffic. WireShark is too complex
EDIT: the socket is XMLSocket not WebSocket

Comment: I don't have an answer for your problem, but here's some technical info. **AS2** is an obsolete version of **ActionScript** and is *extremely* limited in terms of communication means, so **WebSocket** is not on the list of these means. There are, like, three classes: **LoadVars** (url-encoded key/value pairs over **HTTP** requests), **NetConnection** (full-duplex, uses **RTMP** protocol whatever it is with **AMF** object encoding format) and, finally, **XMLSocket** which is actually a good old **TCP** socket limited to sending/receiving **XML** documents.

Comment: I got a file from the game server named "config.xml" in which there is a value tag "SocktPath"... I thought it is a web socket, but from what you said: it must be an XMLSocket. so, is there a way to inspect traffic of XMLSocket ?

Comment: As I previously mentioned, I don't have an answer. I never used any of these tools. Still, I know of them because I've always been on the other side: I devised protocols that allow **SWF** applications to safely communicate with the server **assuming** there's a proxy/sniffer in between and a person who'd wish to alter the messages. This is why I know that it is possible.